# Missing Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

If you go to this http://themeforest.net/item/smartstart-wp-responsive-html5-theme/full_screen_preview/2067920 link, them go to "blog" and check the second post.

You can see like two pictures if you move to left or right arrows.

I would like to first know, if this can only be done in that theme, or maybe there are other plugins to do it? I've searched for plugins on WP Plugin menu, but didnt find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That theme is using a combination of libraries (e.g. jQuery), plugins (e.g. [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)) and custom scripts to accomplish the carousel slider effect.

You can view the source of [custom.js](http://demo.samuli.me/wp/smartstart/wp-content/themes/smartstart/js/custom.js?ver=3.4.1) and learn how to accomplish a similar effect, though the custom scripts do not appear to be published with any kind of open source licensing.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for take the time. The fancybox will make that effect that open a "popup" ajax window to see the image closer, and thats I need too. But I was looking for the rotator thing to put on the news.